# iOs ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL - Getting error Creating file ('fmt?')

Tags: ios, core-audio

Hi I've been trying to create a wav audio file from the below code, but keep getting the error Creating file ('fmt?'). Can anyone help me out here ? Thanks.

My log : 
*2012-11-01 13:33:14.183 Novocaine iOS Example[7456:c07] URL: file://localhost/Users/pier/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/01EBF2C0-2C3A-490D-835E-9C39A3E88E0B/Documents/testrecording.wav

Error: Creating file ('fmt?')*

```
- (id)initWithAudioFileURL:(NSURL *)urlToAudioFile samplingRate:(float)thisSamplingRate numChannels:(UInt32)thisNumChannels
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{

    // Zero-out our timer, so we know we're not using our callback yet
    self.callbackTimer = nil;


    // Open a reference to the audio file
    self.audioFileURL = urlToAudioFile;
    CFURLRef audioFileRef = (CFURLRef)self.audioFileURL;

    AudioStreamBasicDescription outputFileDesc; 

    // Set a few defaults and presets
    self.samplingRate = thisSamplingRate;
    self.numChannels = thisNumChannels;
    self.currentTime = 0.0;
    self.latency = .011609977; // 512 samples / ( 44100 samples / sec ) default

    outputFileDesc.mSampleRate = self.samplingRate;
    outputFileDesc.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    outputFileDesc.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat;
    outputFileDesc.mBytesPerPacket = 4*self.numChannels;
    outputFileDesc.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    outputFileDesc.mBytesPerFrame = 4*self.numChannels;
    outputFileDesc.mChannelsPerFrame = self.numChannels;
    outputFileDesc.mBitsPerChannel = 32;

    CheckError(ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(audioFileRef, kAudioFileWAVEType, &outputFileDesc, NULL, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &_outputFile), "Creating file");
```

.
.
.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why, but I made the following changes and it worked.
One would think wav file would have type kAudioFileWAVType, no?
Anyone care to shine a light on this?

```
outputFileDesc.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked; //changed


CheckError(ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(audioFileRef, kAudioFileCAFType, &outputFileDesc, NULL, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &_outputFile), "Creating file"); //changed
```

Comment: That's not a wav file, it's a caf file. wav editors can't open it.

Answer (score 0):

Unusually, it appears that `ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL`'s WAV file implementation **requires** that the `kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked` flag be explicitly set.

This is unusual because the `kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked` documentation claims that the flag is implied in the OP's case:

> even if this flag is clear, it is implied that this flag is set if the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` is filled out such that the fields have the following relationship:
> `((mBitsPerSample / 8) * mChannelsPerFrame) == mBytesPerFrame`

It's also unusual because other formats, like CAF, just don't care.

**TL;DR** setting the format flags like this will fix the `kAudioFileUnsupportedDataFormatError = 'fmt?'` error:

```
outputFileDesc.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
```